# How use a loop for data.frame (in R)

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have this code:

```
#load library  foreign and mass
library(foreign)
library(MASS)

#read spss file
read.spss("C:\\Users\\Morisato\\Desktop\\Modelação Estatistica e Análise de Dados\\1º Ano\\1º Semestre\\Análise de Dados com Software Estatistico\\Exercicios Regressão Linear\\imc_mest.sav")

#save data frame in a variable dados
dados= data.frame(read.spss("C:\\Users\\Morisato\\Desktop\\Modelação Estatistica e Análise de Dados\\1º Ano\\1º Semestre\\Análise de Dados com Software Estatistico\\Exercicios Regressão Linear\\imc_mest.sav"))

#set seed
set.seed(5)
```

## population length

Y<- 540

## sample length

n<- 30

And I want to make a loop that extracts a sample of 30 elements and do it 50 times and I try this:

```
#create a matrix with 50 rows (sample) and 30 cols (the number os elements)
result <- matrix(ncol=30,nrow=50)

for (i in 1:50){
  result[i,1:30] <- sample(Y, n, replace=F)
} # end for
```

But it only shows the number of elements but i'd like to save the data frame of each sample and save the confidence intervals of those samples too.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. What are `Y` and `n`?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to sample among 540 rows random 50 with 30 random variables, and put that into a matrix?

Comment: yes, i want to extract 30 samples 50 times from 540 population rows

Comment: resultado<- replicate(50, dados[sample(Y, n), ], simplify = FALSE)

intervalo<- lm(imc ~ pabdom + panca + mgorda, dados)

coeficientes<- lapply(resultado, function(x) confint(lm(imc ~ pabdom + panca + mgorda, dados), x))

isn't work, i'd like to substitute 
function(x) confint(lm(imc ~ pabdom + panca + mgorda, dados)
for only a variable named intervalo and than all result appears in a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command will create a list of length 50. Each list element will consist of a random subset of your data frame `dados` with `n` rows. (I assume `Y` represents the number of rows of `dados`.)

```
result <- replicate(50, dados[sample(Y, n), ], simplify = FALSE)
```

Then you can apply this code to obtain confidence intervals of coefficients of linear regression:

```
lapply(result, function(x) confint(lm(NHHD ~ ATD + DASU + DAPE + NRX + MES, x)))
```

This will also return a list of length 50.

Comment: Thank you very much, just one more question if I want to apply confidence intervals or regression coefficient to this table
data<- replicate(50, dados[sample(Y, n), ], simplify = FALSE)

what can I do?

Comment: @user3125157 This is quite vague. Please provide an example.

Comment: I have the follow loop

result<- replicate(50, dados[sample(Y, n), ], simplify = FALSE)

it give me the 50 samples of 30 elements, and my question is, how can I apply a function like confidence intervals or regression coefficient to this table (i mean, apply in each table/sample) and the result appears in a table too

Comment: @user3125157 Please specify which variables should be used in the regression. I simple formula will suffice.

Comment: lm(NHHD~ATD+DASU+DAPE+NRX+MES)